# "HasMoreData" is true even after Receive-Job

Tags: powershell, jobs

I create a simple background job in Powershell:

```
Start-Job {"Hello"}
```

I check with Get-Job:

```
    Id        Name         State         HasMoreData      Location       Command
    --        ----         -----         -----------      --------       -------
    1         Job1         Completed     True             localhost      "Hello"
```

Next, I simply receive the output, and run Get-Job again

```
Receive-Job 1
Get-Job
```

I can see that "HasMoreData" is now false, because I didn't specify the `-keep` parameter.

HOWEVER: it seems that whenever I start a job, not with `Start-Job` or `Invoke-Command`, that this "HasMoreData" parameter does not change to False.

Examples:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_bios -AsJob
Test-Connection . -AsJob
```

Can I bypass this (wrong) behaviour, so that the property HasMoreData switches to False, unless I specify `-keep`?

Thanks!

**Update**: it seems to be for all calls made with the `-AsJob` parameter.  If you run

```
Start-Job {Test-Connection .}
```

it works ("HasMoreData" becomes False after `Receive-Job`), but

```
Test-Connection . -AsJob
```

does not.

Comment: I have exactly this bug with PS3.0 PS4.0 PS5.1 and PS6.1 !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

It's a bug in PowerShell 2.0.

It works fine for Blaine because he's using PowerShell 3, I'd put money on it.

---

Long answer:

The **Start-Job** cmdlet and the **-AsJob** switch work differently. Documentation usually explains that **Start-Job** is intended to run background jobs locally whereas **-AsJob** is intended to start jobs with commands that run on remote computers but creates the job object locally. While that's generally true, **-AsJob** can also be used to run jobs locally, and depending on the command, it's sometimes not even capable of running the command on a remote computer. For example, **Get-WMIObject** invoked with **-AsJob** and **-ComputerName** runs the command on the specified remote computer, whereas **Test-Connection** invoked with **-AsJob** and **-Computername** runs the command locally and pings the specified computer.

I've also seen documentation that explains that **Start-Job** works by local IPC, whereas **-AsJob** makes a connection to the WinRM service of the specified computer, even if it's the localhost, and that PSRemoting must be enabled on the local and target computer(s). Again, it's not quite that straightforward. I've found that I *can* run jobs with the **-AsJob** switch on the localhost with WinRM and PSRemoting both disabled.

In any case, PowerShell starts jobs as one of two JobTypes, PSWmiJob or PSRemotingJob. This is counter-intuitive, because **Start-Job**, which runs background jobs locally, always creates a PSRemotingJob, whereas **-AsJob** usually creates a PSWmiJob, except when it's used with **Invoke-Command**, which always starts a PSRemoting job regardless of whether the command is invoked on a remote computer or the localhost.

Take a look at the following session transcript, in which I created jobs in the varying ways. I tested with three commands: **Get-WMIObject**, which runs on a remote computer when invoked with **-AsJob** and **ComputerName**; **Test-Connection**, which always runs locally when invoked with **-AsJob** (**-ComputerName** specifies which computer to ping, not where to run the command); and **Get-ChildItem**, which doesn't have an **-AsJob** parameter. I started jobs for each one using **Start-Job**, **Invoke-Command -AsJob** on both a remote computer and the local machine, and the native **-AsJob** switch (for commands that have it).

The purpose of the `| %{$_.Name = '<the command preceding the pipe symbol>'}` at the end of each command is to name each job as the command that created it, so it's easier to see in the output which job corresponds to each command. It has no effect on the operation of the jobs, it just renames each job to a more meaningful name immediately after creating it.

What you'll see is that after all the jobs are received (`rcjb * 2>&1|Out-Null` receives them all at once and suppresses output), the HasMoreData property of PSRemotingJob objects is set to False whether they were created by **Start-Job** or **-AsJob**, but the HasMoreData property of PSWmiJob objects remains True. Beyond the examples I've reproduced here, I've found that this holds true consistently.

```
07-17-13 19:44:56.30 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob'}
07-17-13 19:44:56.43 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob'}
07-17-13 19:44:56.46 C:\Users\ainbar» Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} | %{$_.Name = 'Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.13 C:\Users\ainbar» Test-Connection . -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Test-Connection . -AsJob '}
07-17-13 19:44:57.14 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.18 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} -AsJob'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.20 C:\Users\ainbar» Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} | %{$_.Name = 'Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\}'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.80 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.82 C:\Users\ainbar» Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob | %{$_.Name = 'Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob'}
07-17-13 19:44:57.84 C:\Users\ainbar» $fmt_gjb = 'Id','Name','Location',@{l="JobType";e={$_.GetType().name}},@{l='HasMoreData';e={"$($_.HasMoreData)"}},'State','Command'
07-17-13 19:46:21.36 C:\Users\ainbar» gjb|ft -a $fmt_gjb

Id Name                                                                                  Location  JobType       HasMoreData     State Command
-- ----                                                                                  --------  -------       -----------     ----- -------
 1 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios}                                     localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
 3 Get-WMIObject win32_bios -AsJob                                                       localhost PSWmiJob      True        Completed Get-WMIObject
 5 Get-WMIObject win32_bios -AsJob -ComputerName ai8460p                                 ai8460p   PSWmiJob      True        Completed Get-WMIObject
 7 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob         localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
 9 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob   ai8460p   PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
11 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}                                            localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Test-Connection .
13 Test-Connection . -AsJob                                                              .         PSWmiJob      True        Completed Test-Connection
15 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}                       localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Test-Connection .
17 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} -AsJob          ai8460p   PSRemotingJob True        Completed Test-Connection .
19 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\}                                            localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-ChildItem C:\
21 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob                localhost PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-ChildItem C:\
23 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p   -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob        ai8460p   PSRemotingJob True        Completed Get-ChildItem C:\


07-17-13 19:46:37.94 C:\Users\ainbar» rcjb * 2>&1|Out-Null
07-17-13 19:47:14.52 C:\Users\ainbar» gjb|ft -a $fmt_gjb

Id Name                                                                                  Location  JobType       HasMoreData     State Command
-- ----                                                                                  --------  -------       -----------     ----- -------
 1 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios}                                     localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
 3 Get-WMIObject win32_bios -AsJob                                                       localhost PSWmiJob      True        Completed Get-WMIObject
 5 Get-WMIObject win32_bios -AsJob -ComputerName ai8460p                                 ai8460p   PSWmiJob      True        Completed Get-WMIObject
 7 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob         localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
 9 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_bios} -AsJob   ai8460p   PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-WMIObject win32_bios
11 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}                                            localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Test-Connection .
13 Test-Connection . -AsJob                                                              .         PSWmiJob      True        Completed Test-Connection
15 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .}                       localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Test-Connection .
17 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection .} -AsJob          ai8460p   PSRemotingJob False       Completed Test-Connection .
19 Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\}                                            localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-ChildItem C:\
21 Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob                localhost PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-ChildItem C:\
23 Invoke-Command -ComputerName ai8460p   -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem C:\} -AsJob        ai8460p   PSRemotingJob False       Completed Get-ChildItem C:\


07-17-13 19:47:35.29 C:\Users\ainbar»
```

Bottom line: The bug is in the PSWmiJob object. Regardless of which way the job was created, and regardless of whether the command runs locally or remotely, after a **Receive-Job** the HasMoreData property is set to False if the JobType is PSRemotingJob, but remains True if the JobType is PSWmiJob.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to set HasMoreData to False on a PSWmiJob. **Stop-Job** won't do it, restarting WinRM won't do it, and the property is read-only.

Comment: I had indeed found, after the earlier responses, that this was only the case in Powershell V2.  Thank you Adi, not just for confirming, but for taking the time to explain in such detail and with such effort.

Answer (score 1):

See this output:

```
PS C:\dell> Test-Connection . -AsJob

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
2      Job2            WmiJob          Running       True            .                    Test-Connection


PS C:\dell> Get-Job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
2      Job2            WmiJob          Completed     True            .                    Test-Connection


PS C:\dell> Get-Job Job2 | fl


StatusMessage :
HasMoreData   : True
Location      : .
Command       : Test-Connection
JobStateInfo  : Completed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : d16afbe0-31f7-4189-8d2a-30ede40645c4
Id            : 2
Name          : Job2
ChildJobs     : {Job3}
PSBeginTime   : 7/16/2013 10:22:58 PM
PSEndTime     : 7/16/2013 10:22:58 PM
PSJobTypeName : WmiJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
State         : Completed



PS C:\dell> Get-Job Job3

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      Job3                            Completed     True            .


PS C:\dell> Get-Job Job3 | Receive-Job

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    --------
W4-G9W... localhost       127.0.0.1                                                 32       0
W4-G9W... localhost       127.0.0.1                                                 32       0
W4-G9W... localhost       127.0.0.1                                                 32       0
W4-G9W... localhost       127.0.0.1                                                 32       0


PS C:\dell> Get-Job Job2 | fl


StatusMessage :
HasMoreData   : False
Location      : .
Command       : Test-Connection
JobStateInfo  : Completed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : d16afbe0-31f7-4189-8d2a-30ede40645c4
Id            : 2
Name          : Job2
ChildJobs     : {Job3}
PSBeginTime   : 7/16/2013 10:22:58 PM
PSEndTime     : 7/16/2013 10:22:58 PM
PSJobTypeName : WmiJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
State         : Completed



PS C:\dell> Get-Job Job3

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      Job3                            Completed     False           .
```

You see that the Job2 is the toplevel job and it has a child job created with the name Job3. That is where the actual action is taking place.

Can you receive the child job and check if the HasMoreData is still set?