# Powershell 'Start-Job` versus 'Start-Process'

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm a little confused about the difference between `Start-Job` and `Start-Process` in PowerShell. I know that `Start-Job` will run in the background, but I'm wondering whether things run differently with `Start-Job` than with `Start-Process` and whether there are other implications of using one as opposed to the other . When should you use one over the other, and are there advantages that either has over the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Start-Job** starts a background job and creates a job object that you use to monitor, query, and interact with the job using the cmdlets **Get-Job**, **Receive-Job**, **Wait-Job**, **Stop-Job**, and **Remove-Job**. You won't see any interactive windows or console output until you query the job object with **Receive-Job**. That's what "background job" means - that it runs, but doesn't interact with the logon session. However, if there's any output, that's collected by the job object, and you can retrieve it with **Receive-Job**. You can generally tell if there's data to receive by checking the **HasMoreData** property of the job object, but be careful, that's buggy in PowerShell 2 - remember this? ["HasMoreData" is true even after Receive-Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933732/hasmoredata-is-true-even-after-receive-job/17712776#17712776)

**Start-Process** launches a process that runs interactively.

Comment: Important to note: **Jobs are local to your session.** You cannot do a `Start-Job` in one powershell session and `Receive-Job` in another.